# HTTP testing tool, easily send POST/GET/PUT with Japanese character support (utf-8)

Tags: http, testing

I've seen this link ([HTTP testing tool, easily send POST/GET/PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087185/http-testing-tool-easily-send-post-get-put)) very useful but my requirements now are to support japanese characters (utf-8).

Using RestClient and WFetch, the text are garbled. Any settings need to be done first or any other tool that can support utf-8 response?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but in PHP, I wrote a class to make HTTP requests.

https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/OutgoingHttpRequest.md

I'd be curious to see how it performs with Japanese characters. You may be able to add the

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

utf_encode function in php to encode the response, if you're also getting garbled reponses.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Web Performance and Load tests do what you are asking.  Here's a quick article describing how to create a simple web service request: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182557.aspx.

It does require Visual Studio Ultimate.  If you already have it, then it's a great tool, if you don't you may consider other options that could be less expensive.