# What's an outstanding Chrome or Firefox extension to easily view and set GET URL params, and POST data

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, url-parameters

I would like to have a browser extension to display URL params as a set of keys and values I can modify before executing a GET.

Some sort of interface that looks roughly like this:

```
[x] GET [ ] POST [ ] PUT [ ] DELETE

param: ________   value: ________
param: ________   value: ________
param: ________   value: ________
param: ________   value: ________

data:
|------------------------|
|                        |
|                        |
|________________________|

                      [ submit ]
```

And it would display the result in another window, tab, frame, or whatever, so I wouldn't lose the interface and could tweak parameters and do successive GETs and POSTs.

Does anyone know of an extension like this for Chrome (preferably) or Firefox?

An external program would be alright as well, as long as it's good and multi-platform.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087185/http-testing-tool-easily-send-post-get-put and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075457/http-testing-tool-easily-send-post-get-put-with-japanese-character-support-utf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome Extension: Try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-url-params/jhhjlajfdkofbnhbcjcddngfehfihfln?hl=en-US for simple GET request param modifications!

Answer (score 1):

I personally go with firefox + [httprequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/)

Comment: To be more "complete" I'm going to add some more not listed in the other answers, just hoping it could be useful for someone sooner or later

Comment: First of all, [HTTP LIVE HEADERS](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for Firefox is one of the widely known and used

Comment: Always for Firefox, [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) is another widely known and used one

Comment: For Firefox again, [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) another widely known and used one.

Comment: Last (for now) but not least, [Header Tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/header-tool/) for Firefox (of course): probably not so "famous" as the others mentioned but looks promising to me.

Answer (score 0):

[TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) is probably the most powerful of them. At the same time - its quite easy to grasp on without any external help.

But if you want even easier tool - then try [HackBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hackbar/).